# Нет кода для маркированного списка

Tags: html, jquery

Код html страницы сайта:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ResponsiveSlides.js &middot; Responsive jQuery slideshow</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../responsiveslides.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
    $(function () {

      // Slideshow 2
      $("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: true,
        speed: 300,
        maxwidth: 540
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Slideshow 2 -->
    <ul class="rslides" id="slider2">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Я скачал библиотеку jquery, которая подключает слайдер к сайту.

В примере html страницы сайта со слайдером записан блок с изображениями. При открытии данного сайта можно увидеть данный блок с изображениями и маркированный список с числами, при нажатии на которые осуществляется переключение между изображениями. В консоли код для данного маркированного списка прописан, но в самом файле html кода нет. Где в таком случае его найти?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в `responsiveslides.min.js` очевидно же, а за стили слайдера (и стиль нумерации) отвечает `responsiveslides.css` соответственно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот список генерируется самим слайдером. Если Вы откроете [неминифицированный скрипт](https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/blob/master/responsiveslides.js), то там будут следующие строки:

```
if (settings.pager && !settings.manualControls) {
  var tabMarkup = [];
  $slide.each(function (i) {
    var n = i + 1;
    tabMarkup +=
      "<li>" +
      "<a href='#' class='" + slideClassPrefix + n + "'>" + n + "</a>" +
      "</li>";
  });
  $pager.append(tabMarkup);

  ...
}
```